# In C, why can't you use sscanf() to trim a string?

Tags: c, string

So, if you get a string with `fgets()`, what is wrong with trimming the string this way:

```
  const int stringMax = 80;
       char string[ stringMax ];

  fgets( string , stringMax , stdin );

    // remove trailing <newline> that fgets preserves.
  len = strlen( string );
  if( isspace( string[ len-1 ] ) ) {
    string[ len-1 ] = 0;
    len--;
  }

    // let sscanf do the trimming.
  if( len ) sscanf( string , "%s" , string );

  printf( "string \"%s\" len=[%d]\n" , string , len );
```

Comment: `char* string[ stringMax ];` declares a (variable length) array of pointers... you want `char string[ stringMax ];` a (variable length) array of char.

Comment: Yeah, that was just boneheaded. See my follow-up answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> what is wrong with trimming the string this way: (?)

```
if( len ) sscanf( string , "%s" , string );
```

OP's code has 2 problems:

```
int sscanf(const char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

- The source string `s` is `restrict`.  This implies the side effects of writing to the addresses in `...` do not affect the source.   Since the matching argument to `"%s"` in OP's code is that string - the result is *undefined behavior* (UB) regardless of the content of `s`.
- Even is the overlap of source and destination "worked", `"%s"`, after scanning non-white-space,  stops at the first white-space.  `" abd def "` would become `"abc"` and not `"abc def"`.

> what is wrong with trimming the string this way: (?)

```
if( isspace( string[ len-1 ] ) ) {
```

This has 2 problems:

- `isspace()` is specified for `unsigned char` values and `EOF`.  If `string[len-1] < 0`, the result is UB.
- It is possible to first read a *null chracter* leading to `string[-1]`, accessing outside the `string[]` buffer --> more UB.

---

Some untested `trim()` code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char* trim(char *s) {
  unsigned char *left = (unsigned char *)s;
  while (isspace(*left)) {
    left++;
  }
  size_t len = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  while (left[i]) {
    if (!isspace(left[i++])) {
      len = i;
    }
  }
  s = memmove(left, s, len);
  s[len] = '\0';
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I came across both of those in my more rigorous testing. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if there is no whitespace between the beginning alphanumeric and ending alphanumeric of the input string.

Therefore, `trim()`, `trimright()` and `trimleft()` functions should be considered, instead.

Comment: `sscanf( string , "%s" , string );` remains _undefined behavior_ even if "there is no whitespace between the beginning alphanumeric and ending alphanumeric of the input string" is true.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out with better test cases.

Comment: Where are these `trim()`, `trimright()`, and `trimleft()` of which you speak?